# mysql query for replacing %s

Tags: php, mysql, regex, replace

I have many values in DB having %s in them. I have written a code in PHP to replace them , but I need a query.Can this be done in a query.

My values are like 
**Demand has exceeded all `%s` expectations, and unfortunately, we're unable to ship your `%s` accessory in the time frame we stated in our previous email. `%s` We expect to ship your order by `%s`.**

It can have multiple instances of %s. I want to replace them by  %1$s for 1st concurrence %2$s for second and do on.

I have used regex in my code

```
if(preg_match_all('/(%s)/', $val, $match))
```

and in a loop i did this

```
echo $val =str_replace("%s",'%'.++$j.'$s',$val,$count);
```

but can this all be done by one single query?, never mind for optimization.

Comment: Just pass it to sprintf and then query db with it.

Comment: MySQL actually has a replace method , just google it, replace will replace all occurrences of one string with another one. The BIG problem you need the replaceable content to be dynamic (a counter) , there fore i suggest to create and call a stored procedure which receives both strings and appends the counter. I believe it will not have big difference from what you are doing in php - but if you needed to replace %s with $s only it will be much faster to use REPLACE.

Comment: one more option is to output the content to a file, do the sed (shell command) replacements, and load it back

Comment: I did it via code, just curious to have a query

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to do this?  Your database appears to contain format strings that are intended to be used as the first argument to [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php):

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$qry = $dbh->prepare('SELECT format_string FROM my_table WHERE string_id = ?');

$qry->execute([1234]);
while ($row = $qry->fetch()) printf($row['format_string'], $s1, $s2, ... );
```